# Does Import effect your file size AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

This might be a silly a question. But I am just curious to know if the amount of classes you import into your flash class, affect the size of the class, the size swf file, or the amount of memory allocated. If so, does this affect take place before or after you initiate the class. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more classes you have compiled into your SWF, the larger the size it will be on disk. For example, if you have 10 classes in your SWF, it may be 5k. But if you're using 300 classes, it may be 50k. That will affect the time of the initial download.

As you instantiate more classes, those take memory. The memory is not allocated until the class is instantiated.

Hope that helps.

Comment: To add to this, simply importing the class shouldn't add to the swf size. You have to make references to the classes in order for them to be compiled in to your swf.

Answer (score 2):

If they are not used anywhere they will not be compiled, so the size of the file will not grow. You will only give more work to the compiler.